# Executing function in python after page timeout using selenium API

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have a python script that is utilizing selenium with the chrome webdriver. When I load pages sometimes it'll get stuck because some javascript is trying to load. If I run the line:

```
driver.execute_script("$(window.stop())")
```

that occasionally (but not reliably) works to simulate the stop browser action. My other thought was to change the `page_load_timeout` to 5s. That will throw an error when this annoying javascript isn't loading. I want to stop the page from loading with the timeout, but then run the function that I initially wanted to run... How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

One way is, you have to assert by inspection which element could do the delay and with the element's #id you you can wait for that element to load with a time out.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until((EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.Id, 'id')))

except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

Or you can use the *staleness_of* approach, explained in related SO answers,

```
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def wait_for_page_load(self, timeout=30):
        old_page = self.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        yield
        WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(staleness_of(old_page))
```

Comment: I'm not waiting for an element to appear, the elements are already on the page, but the page is waiting to load some javascript before I can do actions on the elements